# Executar jQuery em onclick de botão

Tags: jquery, asp.net

**Como chamar o jQuery direto no `onclick` do botão?**, por exemplo:

```
<input type="button" id="btnteste" onclick="$("#IDdoTextBox").spectrum("set", $("IDdoCampo").val());" />
```

E não funciona, não retorna erro nem nada. Aliás, no próprio Visual Studio já fica em vermelho como código errado.

A maneira abaixo funciona, porém como falei não quero, visto que vai ser criado tudo dinamicamente em ASP.NET

```
<script>
$("#btnteste").click(function() {
    $("#IDdoTextBox").spectrum("set", $("#IDdoCampo").val());
});
```

Comment: Apenas não funciona ou retorna algum erro no console?

Comment: Gostaria de saber se esta correto, pois tudo indica que não é assim...deve ter algo faltando...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está quebrando a sintaxe do HTML usando "(aspas duplas) dentro do valo do onclick, procure usar '(aspas simple).

Mude de:

```
<input type="button" id="btnteste" onclick="$("#IDdoTextBox").spectrum("set", $("IDdoCampo").val());" />
```

para:

```
<input type="button" id="btnteste" onclick="$('#IDdoTextBox').spectrum('set', $('IDdoCampo').val());" />
```

Answer (score 1):

O melhor a fazer é ficar pelo script, mais sobre isso pode ser visto aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627443/jquery-click-vs-onclick

Mas se pretende mesmo que o conteudo tenha o onclick então tente

```
<input type="button" id="btnteste" onclick="$('#IDdoTextBox').spectrum('set', $('#IDdoCampo').val());" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser pelas aspas tente usar aspas simples assim:

```
<input type="button" id="btnteste" onclick="$('#IDdoTextBox').spectrum('set', $('IDdoCampo').val());" />
```

Comment: mas quando faço no <script> faço com as outras aspas $("#btnEnterAColor").click(function() {
    $("#triggerSet").spectrum("set", $("#enterAColor").val());
});

Comment: @Dorathoto Sim mas como a [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11494/5082) do nosso amigo R3oLoN diz: Você está quebrando a sintaxe do HTML usando "(aspas duplas)

Comment: perfeito..era isso mesmo...bom o visual studio continua mostrando a sintaxe em vermelho. mas funcionou!..valeu

Comment: @Dorathoto valeu foi um prazer ajudar..